# Selecting data from a treeview

Tags: python, sql, select, tkinter, treeview

I use a ttk.TreeView as a multicolumn ListBox which effectively displays the sql data I send to it as a table. When I make a sql query and the treeview displays the queried data, there is the option to select the data, as in the row is highlighted when clicked. Is it possible for me to click a row so that data is highlighted and then click another button that creates a popup window with the data in it to be edited?

Because I am working with SQL, I just need the data to be selected and then I can use it to delete it from the SQL table, not the treeview table. Here is the tree below with an example of some data being selected. Can I pass only the selected data to be edited or deleted or something to that effect?

[image: The tree]

Edit:

```
        def OnDoubleClick(self,event):
            top1=Toplevel(height=600,width=500)
            #frame is just for managing objects not absolutely needed but i think it is good
            #to use frame when using object so i have kept it in
            curItem = self.tree.focus()
            contents =(self.tree.item(curItem))
            selectedetails = contents['values'] 
            #this is what you would use to when presenting the selectedd information


            self.example_var = StringVar()
            self.example_var.set(selectedetails[1])
            self.example_txt = Entry(top1,textvariable=self.example_var)
            self.example.grid(row=1,column=1)
```

I changed the frame for managing objects into a Toplevel and changed where the the entry widget goes so that its the same place (top1). The error message that is produced when I double click on an item in the tree is:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1489, in __call__
        return self.func(*args)
    File "C:\Users\lukeh\Documents\a\test for double click.py", line 278, in OnDoubleClick
        self.example.grid(row=1,column=1)
AttributeError: 'MultiColumnListbox' object has no attribute 'example'
```

When I delete the second half of the code where the self.example starts, the code doesn't actually seem to do anything other than create the Toplevel.

Edit:

When I delete the self.example lines of code and just use `print (selectedetails)` the correct line of data is outputted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first you need to bind a event to your tree iv used double click

```
self.tree.bind("<Double-1>",lambda event :self.OnDoubleClick(event))
#note the OnDoubleClick is the name of the sub that python will look for when tree 
#double clicked
```

next you need to make your subroutine that will be called when tree double click (for my example it is OnDoubleClick)

```
def OnDoubleClick(self, event):
        frame3 = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="frame1", width=300, height=130, bd=5)
        frame3.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=8)
        #frame is just for managing objects not absolutely needed but i think it is good
        #to use frame when using object so i have kept it in
        curItem = self.tree.focus()
        contents =(self.tree.item(curItem))
        selectedetails = contents['values'] 
        #this is what you would use to when presenting the selectedd information
```

Then to access this selected data just use the name of the array with the indentation that you want(in this example selectedetails). I then use string variables to fill in entrys with the selected data.

```
self.example_var = StringVar()
self.example_var.set(selectedetails[1])
self.example_txt = Entry(frame3,textvariable=self.example_var)
self.example_txt.grid(row=1,column=1)
```

Comment: The first part is definitely useful, the double click part. However, when I do click it, it has lots of errors with the second half of your code for me. It doesn't seem to bind the data selected. Is it because I want the whole of the row to be selected?

Comment: what is the error that is produced could u maybe copy and past the name of the error it might be i didn't paste in all the code as when i run it on my coursework it is fine - note if you think it will require more than a comment to solve the problem im fine with talking over skype

Comment: I'll edit my main question with the addition of your code (I changed some of it, maybe that's the problem) and show the error message that is produced.

Comment: I looked over code and it was my bad I forgot to add _text to last line this caused error as was trying to place object that did t exist iv amended my code (look at last lines)

Comment: Yeah, that seems to have fixed the error messages I was getting, amazing what a tiny piece of code can do. Thanks!

Comment: np glad i could help with error messages you tend to get a lot of red lines in shell but what you want to look at with error messages is the line number(willl also show the line of code that has the error next to it) and the error description (last line) - also just a bit more advice when using objects i would add txt or lbl or btn ectra to help with names also the .grid can be on same line as when you are creating the button but i perfer it on line after it as it is more readble